# Is there any way to have kids on a console

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can I have kids on my PS3 without any mods or the Hearthfire DLC?

By the way, I killed Grelod the Kind and still cannot get kids. I want one because I am married, I have a dog too. All I am missing is a kid. Please help. :-(

Comment: The answer is yes in Hearthfire DLC. However you can only have children through adoption.

Comment: I do not want hearthfire!

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for is NO you can't have children in Skyrim without the Hearthfire DLC , this DLC enables you to actually get a child so you can have the ' Perfect little family ' otherthan that you literally can't do it other than mods but that would defeat your question so bottom line the answer is NO.

EDIT: Source , duplicate question.

The family interaction you can have with your spouse are;

- To get the lovers comfort bonus
- To get some money from a home shop
- For a daily meal

to get the lovers comfort bonus
to get some money from a home shop
for a daily meal
Beyond that there is no interaction you can have with your spouse. And no sex out of marriage either, this is a wholesome fun game about slaying dragons.

Comment: What if you kill the parent or something like that? :-/

Comment: I'm sorry abbey but no , alas you can't have children in vanilla skyrim. if you look at my edit it will tell you exactly what you can do with your spouse.